# How to capture chrome while it background or minimized with pywin32

Tags: pywin32

It give only black screen.

Here is the code i tried:

```
def get_screenshot(self):

    # get the window image data
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
    img = img[...,:3]
    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

    return img
```